# The Word נולד by Each Tribe

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, pregnancy-birth, shevatim-12-tribes

The [*Yalkut Shimoni*](https://www.sefaria.org/Yalkut_Shimoni_on_Torah.162.9?lang=bi) uses the word נולד when each tribe was born:

- ראובן **נולד** בי"ד בכסליו מת בן מאה חמשים וחמש שנים
- שמעון **נולד** בכ"ח בטבת ומת בן מאה ועשרים שנה
- לוי **נולד** בי"ו בניסן ומת בן מאה שלושים ושבע שנים
- יהודה **נולד** בט"ו בסיון ומת בן מאה ותשע עשרה שנים
- דן בט' באלול ומת מאה ועשרים וחמש שנה
- נפתלי **נולד** בה' בתשרי ומת בן מאה שלושים ושלוש שנה
- גד בי' במרחשון ומת בן מאה ועשרים וחמש שנים
- אשר בכ' בשבט ומת בן מאה ועשרים ושלש שנים
- יששכר **נולד** בי' באב ומת בן מאה ועשרים ושתים שנים
- זבולון בז' בתשרי ומת בן מאה ועשר שנה
- בנימין **נולד** בי"א במרחשון ומת בן מאה וחמש עשרה שנים

Why by גד ,אשר ,זבולון and דן is the word נולד not mentioned?

Comment: Any chance it's a typo in that edition?

Comment: @DoubleAA: I'm open to the possibility. I'm wondering how do they make the same typo 4 times in a row?

Comment: Find and replace mixup. Or something silly like that. Crazier things have happened.

Comment: In another edition it also writes it as: זבולון בז' בתשרי ומת בן מאה ועשר שנה, without the word נולד following Zevulun for example.

Comment: Yalkut Shimoni wasn't written with the level of precision where these things need to have answers.